# BDCDATA with SELECT-OPTION

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I'm calling a report with `CALL TRANSACTION`. I don't want to use `SUBMIT`. I need to give values to a `SELECT-OPTIONS` opening the button and excluding value `'X'`. This is the code that I found from registration

```
  ls_bdcdata-fnam     = 'BDC_OKCODE'.
  ls_bdcdata-fval     = '=%020'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-dynbegin = 'X'.
  ls_bdcdata-dynpro   = '3000'.
  ls_bdcdata-program  = 'SAPLALDB'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-fnam     = 'BDC_OKCODE'.
  ls_bdcdata-fval     = '=NOSV'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-fnam     = 'BDC_SUBSCR'.
  ls_bdcdata-fval     = 'SAPLALDB                                3010SCREEN_HEADER'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-dynbegin = 'X'.
  ls_bdcdata-dynpro   = '3000'.
  ls_bdcdata-program  = 'SAPLALDB'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-fnam     = 'BDC_OKCODE'.
  ls_bdcdata-fval     = '=ACPT'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-fnam     = 'BDC_SUBSCR'.
  ls_bdcdata-fval     = 'SAPLALDB                                3030SCREEN_HEADER'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.

  ls_bdcdata-fnam     = 'RSCSEL_255-SLOW_E(01)'.
  ls_bdcdata-fval     = 'X'.
  APPEND ls_bdcdata TO lt_bdcdata.
  CLEAR ls_bdcdata.
```

The `SELECT-OPTIONS` is identified by

```
ls_bdcdata-fval     = '=%020'.
```

But when I added a new `SELECT-OPTIONS` to the called report this numeration changed. Can I have the numeration value from the name of the `SELECT-OPTIONS` and not from this `'=%020'` value? So I can prevent new changes of the numeration when I will add new  `SELECT-OPTIONS`.

Comment: Is there a special reason for not using `SUBMIT`?

Comment: yes, this was required. they want to control `NOBINPT` option using `CALL TRANSACTION`. This is not possible with `SUBMIT`

Comment: Could You eventually set PARAMETER ID's so the select options might be populated by the values, You put into the id's in the caller  program???

Comment: Yes I can, but I was trying to avoid this (so i don't have to edit called program). But I didn't find other ways

Comment: That they are for, uaually the callee need not to be edited, only the caller.

Comment: What icbytes wanted to say is that IDs may already be declared provided that called report is a standard report.